# Getting ValueError using GridSearchCV from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, valueerror, gridsearchcv

I want to optimize the learning rate and later on other Hyperparameters of my model using GridSearchCV from sklearn. You can see my code below. Unfortunately I always get the Error: ValueError: learning_rate is not a legal parameter

There are similar problems here (["ValueError: activation is not a legal parameter" with Keras classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908972/valueerror-activation-is-not-a-legal-parameter-with-keras-classifier) or [learning_rate is not a legal parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086301/learning-rate-is-not-a-legal-parameter)) but it didn't help me. I also changed learning_rate in lr or learn_rate but it didn't work.

```
# Sequential API
def create_model(learn_rate=0.01):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learn_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                loss='mean_squared_error',
                metrics=['mae', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error'])

    return model

# Hyperparameter Tuning
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model(), verbose=0)
param_grid = {'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1]}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(grid.best_params_)
```

Hopefully someone can help me with my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work if you use `'learning rate'` as a parameter both in your `create_model` function and in the parameter grid `param_grid` and if you replace `create_model()` with `create_model` in the `KerasRegressor`.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# Sequential API
def create_model(learning_rate=0.01):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(
        optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        loss='mean_squared_error',
        metrics=['mae', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error']
    )

    return model

# Sample data
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, random_state=100)

# Hyperparameter Tuning
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
param_grid = {'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1]}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)
grid.fit(X, y)
print(grid.best_params_)
# {'learning_rate': 0.1}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!! Unfortunately I get another Error: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) But I think this is another issue..